RMW implementation has been specified as 'rmw_fastrtps_cpp' via (...), but rmw_implementation was built only with support for 'rmw_cyclonedds_cpp'
Issue
colcon build fails.
$ export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp && colcon build --cmake-clean-cache --packages-up-to mars_rover
Starting >>> simulation
Finished <<< simulation [0.19s]                
Starting >>> mars_rover
--- stderr: mars_rover                         
CMake Error at /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/rmw_implementation/share/rmw_implementation/cmake/rmw_implementation-extras.cmake:25 (message):
  The RMW implementation has been specified as 'rmw_fastrtps_cpp' via
  get_default_rmw_implementation, but rmw_implementation was built only with
  support for 'rmw_cyclonedds_cpp'.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/rmw_implementation/share/rmw_implementation/cmake/rmw_implementationConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/rcl/share/rcl/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/rcl/share/rcl/cmake/rclConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/libstatistics_collector/share/libstatistics_collector/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/libstatistics_collector/share/libstatistics_collector/cmake/libstatistics_collectorConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/rclcpp/share/rclcpp/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /home/spaceros-user/spaceros/install/rclcpp/share/rclcpp/cmake/rclcppConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)

---
Failed   <<< mars_rover [0.98s, exited with code 1]

Env

mars_rover pkg at space-ros/demos
Docker image osrf/space-ros:humble-2024.07.0.

I'm unsure if that Docker image is a suggested environment for the project I'm testing (space_ros). There's official instruction e.g. space-ros/docker/space_robots, which I tried but come with separate issues (may report somewhere separately), hence I'm trying the Docker image mentioned above instead (without referring to any instruction provided by the project).
In the built-in install space, which I source setup.bash from, there are many colcon packages already built incl. rcl*, rmw*, rosidl* so I assume ros2 is referring to the pkgs from there if they exist.
Is the binary in install space specifically built with rmw_cyclonedds_cpp? I haven't found any clue so far. According to space-ros#149, the project doesn't seem to have made any decision to use a specific DDS.


Seems like rmw_fastrtps_cpp came installed with the Docker image, but I also source built it (humble branch).
$ apt-cache policy ros-humble-rmw-fastrtps-cpp
ros-humble-rmw-fastrtps-cpp:
   Installed: 6.2.7-1jammy.20240728.212513
   Candidate: 6.2.7-1jammy.20240728.212513

$ ros2 pkg xml rmw_fastrtps_cpp
<package format="3">
   <name>rmw_fastrtps_cpp</name>
   <version>6.2.7</version>
:




UPDATE-1. Worked around. I removed install, fetched source by vcs import src_v < exact.repos using the .repos file that came with the Docker image, then rebuilt all source that is basically entire ros2 core along with the leaf pkg that I wanted to use (mars_rover), then the error no longer occurs. This tells me there is/are some built package(s) that were causing the issue. Statically linked to a different DDS?
Question: what package(s) should I rebuild to avoid the colcon error in the title? Rebuilding the entire ROS2 doesn't sound like a sustainable solution as it can take too long.
